# all pop up data position of Jquery mobile show in fixed position

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried to write a form in jquery mobile. all field labels have a popup icon. This form worked well but now there is a problem! When I clicked in bottom popup icon, popup open in top of form and in a fixed position. I dont know what's happened. please help me. thank you.

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="php/formUserP1.php" id="formP1" name="formP2">

        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <h2 class="ui-block-a">

                <sup class="dont-print">
                    <a href="#Page01Tooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                       class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                       title=" "></a>
                </sup>
                <div data-role="popup" id="Page01Tooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                     style="max-width:350px;">
                    <p dir="ltr">
                        Personal Information
                    </p>
                </div>
            </h2>
            <div id="imageBlock" class="ui-block-b" align="center">
                <!-- Image -->
                <div id="imagePreview"></div>

                <div class="fileUpload">
                        <span>
Image
                        </span>
                    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" class="upload" name="image" />
                    <sup class="dont-print">
                        <a href="#uploadImageTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                           class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                           title=" "></a>
                    </sup>
                    <div data-role="popup" id="uploadImageTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                         style="max-width:350px;">
                        <p dir="ltr">
                            Your Image
                        </p>
                        <img src="images/image-sample.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End of Image -->
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="FirstNameFa" id="00" >
                FirstNameFa
                <sup class="dont-print">
                            <a href="#FirstNameFaTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                           class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                           title=" "></a></sup>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="FirstNameFaTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                             style="max-width:350px;">
                            <p dir="ltr">
                                Write your first name using the Persian alphabet.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input"  data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="   "
                           name="FirstNameFa" id="FirstNameFa" maxlength="40" required>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
                    <label for="FirstNameEn">
                        FirstNameEn
                        <sup class="dont-print">
                            <a href="#FirstNameEnTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                           class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                           title=" "></a></sup>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="FirstNameEnTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                             style="max-width:350px;">
                            <p dir="ltr">
                                In Latin script, write your first name as it appears in your passport.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Your First Name in English"
                           name="FirstNameEn" id="FirstNameEn" maxlength="40" required>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
                    <label for="LastNameFa">
                        LastNameFa
                        <sup class="dont-print">
                            <a href="#LastNameFaTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                           class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                           title=" "></a></sup>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="LastNameFaTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                             style="max-width:350px;">
                            <p dir="ltr">
                                Write your family name using the Persian alphabet.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="    "
                           name="LastNameFa" id="LastNameFa" maxlength="40" required>
                    </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
                    <label for="LastNameEn">
                                 .
                        <sup class="dont-print">
                            <a href="#LastNameEnTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                           class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                           title=" "></a></sup>
                        <div data-role="popup" id="LastNameEnTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                             style="max-width:350px;">
                            <p>
                                In Latin script, write your family name as it appears in your passport.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Your Last Name in English"
                           name="LastNameEn" id="LastNameEn" maxlength="40" required>
                </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="Gender">
                <legend>
                    Gender
                    <sup class="dont-print">
                        <a href="#GenderTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                           class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                           title=" "></a></sup>
                    <div data-role="popup" id="GenderTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                             style="max-width:350px;">
                        <p dir="ltr">
                            What is your gender
                        </p>
                        <ul dir="ltr">
                            <li>
                                Male
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                Female
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </legend>
                    <label for="Male" class="radio-inline">

                        <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="Gender" value="1" id="Male" required>
                    </label>
                    <label for="Female" class="radio-inline">

                        <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="Gender" value="2" id="Female"
                    </label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="PassportNo">
                PassportNo
                <sup class="dont-print">
                    <a href="#PassportNoTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                        class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                        title=" "></a></sup>
                <div data-role="popup" id="PassportNoTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                     style="max-width:350px;">
                    <p dir="ltr">
                        Write your passport number.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" placeholder=": A11487661"
                   name="PassportNo" id="PassportNo" maxlength="30" required>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
                Nationality
                <sup class="dont-print">
                    <a href="#NationalityTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                   class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                   title=" "></a></sup>
                <div data-role="popup" id="NationalityTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a">
                        What is your nationality

                </div>
        </div>
        <div>
                BirthDate

                    <a href="#BirthDateTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                        class=" ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                        title="Help"></a>
                <div data-role="popup" id="BirthDateTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a">
                        Write your birthdate as it appears in your passport (day, month, year according to the Gregorian calendar)
                </div>
        </div>


        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="CountryBirth">
                CountryBirth
                <sup class="dont-print">
                    <a href="#CityBirthTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
               class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
               title=" "></a></sup>
            <div data-role="popup" id="CityBirthTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                 style="max-width:350px;">
                <p dir="ltr">
                    Write the name of the country and the city in which you were born.
                </p>
            </div>
            </label>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <select class="form-control" name="CountryBirth" id="CountryBirth" dir="ltr">
                    <option value="">

                    </option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" placeholder=" . : "
                   name="CityBirth" id="CityBirth" maxlength="30">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="CountryResidence">
                CountryResidence
                <sup class="dont-print">
                    <a href="#CountryResidenceTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
               class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
               title=" "></a></sup>
            <div data-role="popup" id="CountryResidenceTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                 style="max-width:350px;">
                <p dir="ltr">
                    Write the name of the country and the city in which you live now.
                </p>
            </div>
            </label>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <select class="form-control" name="CountryResidence" id="CountryResidence"  dir="ltr">
                    <option value="">

                    </option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" placeholder=" . : "
                   name="CityResidence" id="CityResidence" maxlength="30">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="HomeTel">
                HomeTel
                <sup class="dont-print">
                <a href="#HomeTelTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
               class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
               title=" "></a></sup>
            <div data-role="popup" id="HomeTelTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                 style="max-width:350px;">
                <p dir="ltr">
                    Write your home phone number, including the city and country code.
                </p>
            </div>
            </label>
            <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" placeholder=": 00982122414393"
                   name="HomeTel" id="HomeTel" maxlength="15">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="Mobile">
                Mobile
                <sup class="dont-print">
                <a href="#MobileTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
               class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
               title=" "></a></sup>
            <div data-role="popup" id="MobileTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                 style="max-width:350px;">
                <p dir="ltr">
                    Write your cell phone number, including the country code.
                </p>
            </div>
            </label>
            <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" placeholder=": 0098912345678901"
                   name="Mobile" id="Mobile" maxlength="15" >
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="WorkTel">
                WorkTel
                <sup class="dont-print">
                <a href="#WorkTelTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
               class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
               title=" "></a></sup>
            <div data-role="popup" id="WorkTelTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                 style="max-width:350px;">
                <p dir="ltr">
                    Write your work phone number, including the city and country code.
                </p>
            </div>
            </label>
            <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" placeholder=": 00982122414393"
                   name="WorkTel" id="WorkTel" maxlength="15">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain"> <!-- for inline label and input -->
            <label for="Email">
Email
                <sup class="dont-print">
                    <a href="#EmailTooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"
                        class="my-tooltip-btn ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini"
                        title=" "></a></sup>
                <div data-role="popup" id="EmailTooltip" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a"
                     style="max-width:350px;">
                    <p dir="ltr">
Your email address.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </label>
            <input type="email" data-clear-btn="true" class="form-control" name="Email" id="Email" disabled/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control dont-print" data-icon="arrow-l" data-inline="true" name="next02" id="next02" value=" ">

        <br>

        </form>
```

Comment: I opened my page in firefox and it work. But in Chrome It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-position-to="window"` to the buttons that open the pop-ups.

[jQuery Mobile pop-up position.](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/#Position)

Comment: thank you. I tryed this, but this is not solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

> href="#Page01Tooltip" data-rel="popup" data-transition="flip"

Use there: data-position="window"